# Failed resolution of: Landroid/graphics/ColorSpace

Tags: android, android-studio, fresco

It worked fine before I updated my Android Studio to 2020.3.1.
I just discovered that android.graphics.ColorSpace was introduced in Android API 26.
So all the devices which are under Android 8 will throw this exception.
But how could it pass the compile?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
Failed resolution of: Landroid/graphics/ColorSpace;
com.facebook.imageutils.ImageMetaData.getColorSpace (ImageMetaData.java:31)
com.facebook.imagepipeline.image.EncodedImage.readImageMetaData (EncodedImage.java:398)
com.facebook.imagepipeline.image.EncodedImage.internalParseMetaData (EncodedImage.java:363)
com.facebook.imagepipeline.image.EncodedImage.parseMetaData (EncodedImage.java:341)
com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.NetworkFetchProducer.notifyConsumer (NetworkFetchProducer.java:187)
com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.NetworkFetchProducer.maybeHandleIntermediateResult (NetworkFetchProducer.java:151)
com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.NetworkFetchProducer.onResponse (NetworkFetchProducer.java:108)
com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.NetworkFetchProducer$1.onResponse (NetworkFetchProducer.java:75)
com.facebook.imagepipeline.backends.okhttp3.OkHttpNetworkFetcher$2.onResponse (OkHttpNetworkFetcher.java:185)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run (RealCall.java:504)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

The exception was threw by this method.

```
private ImageMetaData readImageMetaData() {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    ImageMetaData metaData = null;
    try {
      inputStream = getInputStream();
      metaData = BitmapUtil.decodeDimensionsAndColorSpace(inputStream);
      mColorSpace = metaData.getColorSpace();
      Pair<Integer, Integer> dimensions = metaData.getDimensions();
      if (dimensions != null) {
        mWidth = dimensions.first;
        mHeight = dimensions.second;
      }
    } finally {
      if (inputStream != null) {
        try {
          inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          // Head in the sand
        }
      }
    }
    return metaData;
  }
```

But there was already a `ColorSpace` usage in this method and it did check the API level before using it.

```
public static ImageMetaData decodeDimensionsAndColorSpace(InputStream is) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(is);
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = DECODE_BUFFERS.acquire();
    if (byteBuffer == null) {
      byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(DECODE_BUFFER_SIZE);
    }
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    try {
      options.inTempStorage = byteBuffer.array();
      BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);

      ColorSpace colorSpace = null;
      if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        colorSpace = options.outColorSpace;
      }
      return new ImageMetaData(options.outWidth, options.outHeight, colorSpace);
    } finally {
      DECODE_BUFFERS.release(byteBuffer);
    }
  }
```

Here are what I tried.

1. Gradle clean command.
2. Build -> Clean project.
3. Build -> Rebuild project.
4. Change `buildToolsVersion` to the latest.
5. Change `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` to 2.5.0.
6. Add multidex-config.txt and multidex-config.pro

But none of these worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My team faced the same issue after we migrated our project to Gradle 7.
We started to see fatal exceptions (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError) saying that in com.facebook.imageutils.ImageMetaData.getColorSpace (ImageMetaData.java:31) Landroid/graphics/ColorSpace could not be resolved. After a decent amount of coffee, we realized that the app crashes only in release configuration, which means that it has something to do with the proguard configuration. And the guess was right, the following wildcard rule fixed the issue

```
-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }
```

But I wanted to narrow it down to a specific class. So I started digging in usage.txt file (the one generated by proguard, in conjunction with seeds.txt), and this is what I came up with

```
-keep class com.facebook.imagepipeline.image.EncodedImage { *; }
```

I wonder if this will fix the issue you faced as well.

Comment: This is awesome. But I'm scared of upgrading again. So I need several weeks to finish the ongoing project to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in these lines of code.

```java
ColorSpace colorSpace = null;

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    colorSpace = options.outColorSpace;
}
```

When a system that does not support that particular class, you can't refer it's object at all but you can still declare it. So change to this should work.

```java
ColorSpace colorSpace;

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    colorSpace = options.outColorSpace;
}
```

And you will need to adjust the `return` too. Put it in an `if-else` statement.

```java
return new ImageMetaData(options.outWidth, options.outHeight, colorSpace);
```

Comment: These are source codes of Fresco. So there's no way to change it. The problem is that everything worked fine before I update Android Studio. There's no compile error nor runtime error. And the funny thing is that the codes you pointed out doesn't throw any exception. The `metaData.getColorSpace()` is where it throw exception.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't give a runtime error on android 8 and below? That just doesn't make sense. It compiled fine because of your target SDK 26+. That is just basic Java syntax. Your stacktrace is clearly a runtime exception on android 8 or below. If you wanna target your app for SDK 25 and below, and still wanna using `ColorSpace`, that is just not gonna work. You must give an alternative.

Comment: I just rolled back to Android Studio 4.1.3. Everything works great now. No more errors. That's why it's so weird. And there's no one talking about this issue on Github issues of Fresco. I think this is about the Gradle plug in.